# Add new column in dataframe by adding number beginning by 1 in each groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1      COL2 
Group_234 1
Group_234 2
Group_234 3
Group_234 4
Group_89  5
Group_89  6
Group_232 7
Group_232 8
Group_232 9
```

How can I add a `COL3` where for each `COL1` Group, I begin a new Group number beginning by 1? And also change the `COL2` values in a `COL4` where I begin in 1 in each new `COL3` group such as :

```
COL1      COL2 COL3    COL4 
Group_234 1    Group_1 1
Group_234 2    Group_1 2
Group_234 3    Group_1 3
Group_234 4    Group_1 4
Group_89  5    Group_2 1
Group_89  6    Group_2 2
Group_232 7    Group_3 1
Group_232 8    Group_3 2
Group_232 9    Group_3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print (df)
         COL1  COL2
0   Group_234     1
1   Group_234     2
2   Group_234     3
3   Group_234     4
4    Group_89     5
5    Group_89     6
6   Group_232     7
7   Group_232     8
8   Group_232     9
9   Group_234    10 <-difference if repated same groups values
10  Group_234    11 <-difference if repated same groups values
```

You can count consecutive values by compare difference of column `COL1` with cumulative sum and then use this values for counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['COL3'] = 'Group_' + df['COL1'].ne(df['COL1'].shift()).cumsum().astype(str)

#alternative if not consecutive counts
df['COL31'] = 'Group_' + df.groupby('COL1', sort=False).ngroup().add(1).astype(str)

df['COL4'] = df.groupby('COL3').cumcount().add(1)

#alternative if not consecutive counts
df['COL41'] = df.groupby('COL1').cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
         COL1  COL2     COL3    COL31  COL4  COL41
0   Group_234     1  Group_1  Group_1     1      1
1   Group_234     2  Group_1  Group_1     2      2
2   Group_234     3  Group_1  Group_1     3      3
3   Group_234     4  Group_1  Group_1     4      4
4    Group_89     5  Group_2  Group_2     1      1
5    Group_89     6  Group_2  Group_2     2      2
6   Group_232     7  Group_3  Group_3     1      1
7   Group_232     8  Group_3  Group_3     2      2
8   Group_232     9  Group_3  Group_3     3      3
9   Group_234    10  Group_4  Group_1     1      5
10  Group_234    11  Group_4  Group_1     2      6
```